# Datatables server side paging codeigniter larger query with joins DOCTRINE

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, datatable, server-side

I have a datatable with server side paging:

```
$('#answers').dataTable({
    //"processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax":{
        url :"/ajaxserverside/", // json datasource
        type: "post",  // method  , by default get
        'data': {
            category: category,
            topic: topic,
            lawyer: lawyer
            //action: 'search',
            // etc..
         },
        error: function(){  // error handling


        }
    }
});
```

So my problem is that on the controller below I have some rather bigger queries that take sometime. Sometimes up to 15,000 rows.

I have been able to get the query and get number of total records and total filtered records. 
The problem is that every time I change pages the same controller runs again and has to execute that HUGE query and takes extra time. I wish i could find a way that it would just save the number of total records and not have to execute that HUGE query again and use that to count the number of records again.

Below I first run the query and get the number of total records. Then I run the same query but now I let only 10 rows per page and make it start with the correct offset upon each page redraw.

So if anyone has an idea on how to do this faster that would be great thx!

```
public function ajaxserverside() {
   $query1 = $this->em->createQuery('INSERT BIG QUERY HERE');
   $answers1 = $query1->getArrayResult();
   $count = count($answers1);

   $query = $this->em->createQuery('INSERT BIG QUERY HERE')->setMaxResults($_POST['length'])->setFirstResult($_POST['start']);
   $answers2 = $query->getArrayResult();

    foreach($answers2 as $answer2) {
        $sub_array = array();  
        $sub_array[] = $answer2['subject'];  
        $sub_array[] = $answer2['name'];  
        $sub_array[] = $answer2['replies'];  
        $sub_array[] = $answer2['replies'];  

        $data[] = $sub_array;  
    }

     $output = array(  
            "draw"                    =>     intval($_POST["draw"]),  
            "recordsTotal"          =>      intval($count),  
            "recordsFiltered"     =>     intval($count),  
            "data"                    =>     $data  
       );  
       echo json_encode($output); 
}
```

Comment: Datatable is not the right tool when you are handling more that 5 thousand records...you should implement real pagination using `limit x,y`

Comment: @Hackerman Server side paging does that actually, read the docs.

Comment: Keep dreaming...that is not how datatables works at all....anyway, good look.

Comment: @Hackerman go ahead and answer the question with "real pagination" just need it to be AJAX based (client requirement). Using CodeIgniter 3.x, Doctrine and MYSQL.

Comment: No trabajo gratis...Preguntas de este tipo suelen ser muy largas y se escapan del scope....Ademas me da pajita u.u